# Behaviour of INDEX in RDBMS

Tags: mysql, indexing

**Q1 =>** Does an INDEX get purged and created on each insert, update, delete?
**Q2 =>** If yes, how to use an index in a table where there will be 60% read, 30% insert, 10% delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No!  An index is updated on each operation, but it is not rebuilt on each operation (that would have a completely prohibitive cost).
2. Moot since the answer to Q1 is No.

Answer (score 2):

The indexes are "maintained" for each insert/update/delete. That means the affected records of the affected indexes will be inserted/deleted.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/